# OneDrive FB create Folder with Microsoft Graph API Powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

I just want to create a folder one my OneDrive for Buiness Account through the Graph API. After many hours I got stuck with an error which I really can't comprehend. It says that the property 'Attributes' does not exist on type 'oneDrive.folder' and I should not use this property. The problem is that I don't use this property. After alot of research I think it has something to do with the pinned metadata or something like that. But in gerneral I really dont know what to do futher.

I used the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview) and another website to create this script.

The Error:

```
-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException 
The property 'Attributes' does not exist on type 'oneDrive.folder'.
Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.
```

And this is my code:

```
$clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$tenantId = "XXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com"
$clientSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'


$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"


$body = @{
    client_id     = $clientId
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
}

$tokenRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
$token = ($tokenRequest.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token
Write-Host $token


$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/<ID XXXXXXX>/drive/root/children"
$method = 'POST'
$head= @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} 
$postPara= @{
name= "NewFolder"
folder= {}
} | ConvertTo-Json


$antwort = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $head -Uri $uri -Method $method -Body $postPara -ContentType "application/json"
Write-Host $antwort
```

It really should work and I'm sitting on this sample task for over 10 Hours ._.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with you code is

```
$postPara= @{
name= "NewFolder"
folder = {}
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

If you just output $postPara you will see the issue is because your missing the @ in front of value in folder you will actually get the details from the underlying script populated in there. so try

```
$postPara= @{
name= "NewFolder"
folder = @{}
} | ConvertTo-Json
$postPara
```

Which should fix it.A good diag tool is also to use fiddler to look at the request being sent to server.